# How to get node values in XML using VBScript?

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to save all the repeated nodes to an array for my QTP automation.

When we use the below code we get all the repeated nodes present in the XML.
Example:

```vb
strXmlPCoverage = /cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim

Set nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strXmlPCoverage)
PathLength = nodes.Length
```

Let's say the `PathLength` returned "6" tags present in the XML as repeated tags.

```
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[0]
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[1]
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[2]
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[3]
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[4]
/cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[5]
```

Now I want to save all those 6 different paths to array. I'm not able to identify the property that displays the values stored in `nodes`.

```vb
Set nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strXmlPCoverage)
PathLength = nodes.Length
For Each NodeItem In nodes
    ArrAllNodes(i) = NodeItem.nodeValue
Next
```

The above code stores value of that node to Array instead of the node itself. Can you please help me how to store the nodes to array instead of node values

**Output displayed by the code:**

```vb
ArrAllNodes(0) = abc
ArrAllNodes(1) = xyz
...
```

**Output Expected:**

```vb
ArrAllNodes(0) = /cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[0]
ArrAllNodes(1) = /cts:InsuranceClaim/cts:MedicalClaim[1]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NodeValue` property gives you the *value* of a node. What you're looking for is the *path* of the node. DOM objects don't have a method/property providing that information, so you need to determine the path yourself by traversing upwards in the DOM tree (via the `ParentNode` property).

Something like this might give you a starting point:

```vb
Function HasSiblings(n)
    HasSiblings = (TypeName(n.PreviousSibling) = "IXMLDOMElement") Or _
                  (TypeName(n.NextSibling) = "IXMLDOMElement")
End Function

Function GetIndex(n)
    If n.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Then
        GetIndex = 0
    Else
        GetIndex = GetIndex(n.PreviousSibling) + 1
    End If
End Function

Function GetPath(n)
    path = "\" & n.NodeName

    'add index if node has siblings
    If HasSiblings(n) Then
        path = path & "[" & GetIndex(n) & "]"
    End If

    'add parent path if current node is not the document element
    If TypeName(n.ParentNode) = "IXMLDOMElement" Then
        path = GetPath(n.ParentNode) & path
    End If

    GetPath = path
End Function
```

The above code is just a sample with plenty room for improvement, though. For instance, it doesn't check if siblings actually have the same node name.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Will look into this.